# ARGOX Mobile Computer SDK

Tags: c#, windows, sdk, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I search for Argox mobile SDK for .NET C#.
I was downlod SDK from http://www.argox.com/content2011.php?sno=0000033&P_ID=53
but it not working, couse it's for c++ I think... ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked there web site and the internet, there should be some .NET examples installed with the SDK: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zPo5BIItBLEJ:www.argox.com/file.php%3FA_ID%3D213+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk

I did not finish to download and install the SDK. If it really does only support C/C++ as written here http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VTResc3njWYJ:www.koncept-l.pl/assets/Wsparcie/Pliki-do-pobrania/Terminale_kolektory_danych_komputery/Terminale-reczne/Argox_PT-60_Programming_manual_v1.2-.pdf+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk you have to build your own .NET library using P/Invoke on the native API.

AFAIS the scanner API uses messages to inform a listener about scanned data is ready:
BOOL API_Register(hwnd)
That can be used from .NET via a P/Invoke and using the forms handle as hwnd parameter. You have also to implement a MessageWindow and listen for SM_Data_Ready (see the PT-60 SDK include header file for the const value). Then your code can call API_GetBarData (another p/invoke to define) to read the actual barcode data.

If you need help implementing a .NET library for the PT-60, do some more search on P/Invoke. There are also some auto-generators 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx

(https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+p%2Finvoke+lib)

Comment: As the PT-60 is not that powerfull (128MB RAM, 266Mhz clock) restrict your self to Compact Framework 1.0 or 2.0. Beside the PT-60 SDK you also need to download and install a PT-60 or standard WinCE5 Platform SDK

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Your answer is realy good but I can't find SYSAPIAX.DLL file... I install PT-60 SDK and it haven't got the dll files...

Comment: Do you have found a SYSAPIAX.h and a SYSAPIAX.lib? I was unable to install the SDK correctly as in my wine system I dont have any programming tools installed and the PT60 SDK installer only installed the wince5 platform files.

Comment: Hello, I assume that there is an additional software sdk you need. It si called Arogox SDK and comes on CD-R with the handhelds. I dont have access to this and so I cannot help any further. The PT60 sdk only installs the WinCE5 platform sdk.