# FULL SDK for argox pt-60

Tags: c++, dll, sdk, smart-device

I watched this answer.
[ARGOX Mobile Computer SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502470/argox-mobile-computer-sdk/12505945#12505945)

I need scanapiax.h and sysapiax.h files and theirs .dll and .lib.

I have CD-R, but there is no this sources on it:(

Maybe someone solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This libraries is situated on mobile computer!

"C:/Windows/SDK"